# How to correctly split a column that contain either forward or backward brackets

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to extract text between two (either forward or backward brackets) from a column in a file.

Each row conains either two foraward or two reverse brackets:

```
C]chr2:29446394]
[chr1:154142875[A
```

I've tried:

```
@locus = split /\]/\[/, $string;
my $position = $locus[1];
```

I was able to extract either lines with forward or backward brackets
`split /\[/, $string or split /\]/, $string`  but can't figure out how to write a statement that would accomadate both casses. Please suggest something.

Thanks

Comment: `The code I've tried didn't work` This is a bad problem statement. Could you [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38543260/edit) to clarify how does it fail at its task?

Comment: So you want `chr2:29446394` or `chr1:154142875` from those strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the *branch reset* pattern, and capture everything either between two closing square brackets or two opening square brackets

Note that the `/x`modifier allows me to add spaces to make the regex a little more readable

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my @columns = qw/ C]chr2:29446394] [chr1:154142875[A /;

for my $col ( @columns ) {
    next unless $col =~ / (?|
        \[ ([^[]*) \[
        |
        \] ([^]]*) \]
    ) /x;
    my $val = $1;
    print "$val\n";
}
```

#### output

```
chr2:29446394
chr1:154142875
```

Answer (score 0):

You could match (not split) the string with this regex:

```
(\[|\]).*?\1
```

- `(\[|\])` matches either `[` or `]`
- `.*?` lazy regex; matches the minimal text after the previous token...
- `\1` ...until the token which was coming first (either `[` or `]`)

Answer (score 0):

This will find all matching substrings which:

- start from `[` or `]`
- contain 0-N symbols before next `[` or `]`

the value you are looking for is in the second parentheses. You can refer it using `$2` internal variable:

```
while ($string =~ /([\[\]])([^\[\]]*)\1/g) {
    #do something with $2
}
```

Comment: It's the variable with the content of the brackets; it refers to one different match for each iteration (while matches exist).

Answer (score -1):

Please try as below:

```
@locus = split /[\]\[]/, $string;
my $position = $locus[1];
```